# loading data based on conditions in APACHE PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Problem statement-
I want to check if value of column in relation xyz is even then load first 10 fields(1-10) of a file abc and if not then load another 10(11-20).

Relation XYZ
123

Relation ABC
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t

if 123 is even then 
relation PQR should have a-j 
other wise  k-t

Could somebody help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a storage function to do that.

See the implementation of CSVExcelStorage http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.java for example.

Comment: Thanks, Extracted what i needed :)